# Electron webContents.ipc returns undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to register event handlers for IPC-Events on the webContents Property of my BrowserWindow, but I get a Error, which states that the Property is undefined. But the docs says I can use this Property to register handlers specific for my window.

Link to the docs: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsipc-readonly

```
let window = new BrowserWindow({
  title: "First Window"
});
window.loadFile("public/index.html");
window.webContents.ipc.on('my-window-event', () => {
  console.log('my-window-event received');
});
```

Result:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ipc')`

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing, quite strange... is this perhaps because I'm using the system-wide Electron shipped by Arch Linux?

Comment: Not really. The only solution I came up is to listen to the 'ipc-message' event on the webContents object. It's not a good solution, because you need a switch statement if you want to catch multiple events which doesn't make the handler very readable if you have lots of ipc events you want to listen for and thus lots of cases.

Here is an example:
`window.webContents.on('ipc-message', async (event, channel, args) => { // do some work here... }`);